# Xaml editor not working properly with Xamarin in VS 2015

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

When I try to edit a **Xaml** file in the **PCL** I don't get any **Intelligence** from the editor and I can't drag and drop controls from the **Xaml tool box** as shown in the attached GIF.

As shown in the GIF , I try to open xaml file with **XAML Designer** and also with **XAML Designer with Encoding** with no success.
 The Error I get is:

> The file cannot be opened with selected editor.
>  Please choose another
>   editor.

I am using VS 2015 community Update 3 with Xamarin.
Things I tried:
1) Updated the xamarin.forms for the solution.
2) Restarted VS.

[image: The problem I am having!]

This is my Xaml Designer settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms doesn't currently support visual designers for XAML files.

There is not yet a visual designer for generating XAML in Xamarin.Forms applications, so all XAML must be hand-written.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms-xaml-designer/

You can used Intellisense for Xamarin.Forms:
http://brianlagunas.com/getting-intellisense-for-xamarin-forms/

Comment: The Intellisense in the second link doesn't exist.

Comment: Try,  
change your file for Source Code (Text) Editor e restart the Visual Studio.
You can create a new file xaml for test.

Comment: That's what I eventually did, Intellisense works, but tool box not.

Comment: Only for  intellisense code support. The version Cycle 9 for Xamarin.Forms Alpha intellisense XAML of code is extremely good, but, awatting Stable version.

Answer (score 0):

use this link it worked for me after hours of googleing

http://codeworks.it/blog/?p=197

download schema file from this link if you dont have it

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atsushieno/monodroid-schema-gen/master/android-layout-xml.xsd